# How to separate column into two separate columns by condition App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to take the Data in the scan it columns and conditionally filter it into the commercial or manufacturing sheet.

I tried writing a formula as an if function basically saying if it equals "Company" put it in manufacturing column, if not(if the rest) then put into commercial column.

I tried coding it backend in app script, but had an issue grabbing the last row from scan it and correctly adding the item #, vendor, and quantity into the last row of either Commercial or Manufactured.

The scan it section is an importrange function so more data will be entered into it once the code is working correctly.

I ran into dead ends with both. This is obviously an advanced code and I only did a little bit of coding in college. Below is a script that I had been messing with trying to get it to filter the data properly, but I couldn't get it to run. Any help would be appreciated!

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1') 
  
  //Get last rows for MFG
  var mfgvalues = sheet.getRange(3, 5, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  //var mfglast = mfgvalues.filter(String).length;

  //Get last rows for Comm
  var commvalues = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  //var commlast = commvalues.filter(String).length;

  //Get last rows for Scann
  var scanvalues = sheet.getRange(2, 12, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  //var scanlast = scanvalues.filter(String).length;

  //Filter Accordingly
  if (scanvalues == "IMMCO") {
    
    var scanrange = sheet.getRange("L2:N").getLastRow().getValues();
    //var scanlastrow = scanrange.getLastRow().getValues();
    var mfgrow = sheet.getRange("E3:G").getLastRow();
    scanlastrow.copyTo(mfgrow)
    
  } else {
    var scanrange = sheet.getRange("L:N").getLastRow.getValues();
    //var scanlastrow = scanrange.getLastRow().getValues();
    var commrow = sheets.getRange("A3:C").getLastrow()
    scanlastrow.copyTo(commrow)
    
  }
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D0FvVoTADi3t3ENPceB14QYYI4lNI6C3xj2OF-St7Is/edit?usp=sharing

[GOOGLE SHEET OUTPUT WANTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0yZB.png)

Comment: Please share the sample sheet in public. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383). And please include the expected output in your sample sheet.

Comment: @RonM Are you able to view it? I am new to posting a question on here.

Comment: Yes. I can view it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option1:

Using [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to filter your data set if vendor name is equal to "COMPANY" as mentioned in your description

**Formula in Cell A3:**

```
=filter(L3:N,LEN(L3:L)>0,UPPER(M3:M)<>"COMPANY")
```

**Formula in Cell E3:**

```
=filter(L3:N,LEN(L3:L)>0,UPPER(M3:M)="COMPANY")
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

### Option2:

Using apps script to filter your data set.

**Sample Code:**

```
function filter(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  //Get item count for Scann
  var scanCnt = sheet.getRange('L3:L').getValues().flat().filter(String).length;
  Logger.log(scanCnt);

  //Get last rows for Comm
  var commLastRow = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat().filter(String).length;
  Logger.log(commLastRow);

  //Get last rows for MFG
  var mfgLastRow = sheet.getRange('E1:E').getValues().flat().filter(String).length;
  Logger.log(mfgLastRow);

  //Get Scann data if item count is not zero
  if(scanCnt){
    var commItem = [];
    var mfgItem = [];
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(3,12,scanCnt,3);
    var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
    //Loop all scann data and separate mfg with comm
    Logger.log(data.length)
    data.forEach(item => {
      Logger.log(item);

      if(item[1].toUpperCase() == "COMPANY"){
        mfgItem.push(item);
      }else{
        commItem.push(item);
      }
    });

    Logger.log(mfgItem);
    Logger.log(commItem);

    //Append comm items
    sheet.getRange(commLastRow+1,1,commItem.length,commItem[0].length).setValues(commItem);
    //Append mfg items
    sheet.getRange(mfgLastRow+1,5,mfgItem.length,mfgItem[0].length).setValues(mfgItem);


    //Optional: Clear content of scann column
    dataRange.clearContent();
  }
  
}
```

**What it does?**

1. Get the item count to filter in Scan it column by selecting the range `L3:L`. Get its value. Change 2-d array to 1-d array using array.flat(). Use array.filter() to remove empty values. Then get its length
2. Get the last row of Commercial(ColumnA) and Manufactured(ColumnE) column.
3. If item count obtained in step1 is not zero. Then get the data range and its value
4. Loop all data value (by row) one-by-one. Check if `vendor` index is equal to "COMPANY" then add it to `mfgItem` array. Else, add it to `commItem` array
5. Append `mfgItem` and `commItem` under Manufactured Column and Commercial Column
6. (Optional) Clear the data under Scan-it Column

Note:

- You can check the execution log to further understand the procedure done. I included some debug logs in the sample code.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That worked great! We are using an importrange for the scan it data which through off the code, but I was able to use the formulas to get it to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Is there a way to use this same formula for the filter, BUT also allow for manual entry in both the commercial and manufactured columns?

Comment: It is not possible to edit entries that was filtered using filter(). It will prevent the filter result to be expanded in the cells. You might want to re-consider using the script. You just need to get the data from a different spreadsheet/ or from a different sheet

Comment: Just let me know if you need further assistance on how to do that.